# Automatic FrameTicks with MaTeX style

Tags: plotting, ticks, matex

I'm currently working on generating several function plots and have been using the following code as a template:

```
<< MaTeX`
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{(*y-axis*)
    Table[{x, 
      MaTeX[x, "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 1.1]}, {x, 
      0.1 Range[-10, 10]}], 
    Table[{x, 
      MaTeX["", "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 0.2]}, {x, 
      0.1 Range[-10, 10]}]}, {(*x-axis*)
    Table[{x, 
      MaTeX[x, "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 1.2]}, {x, 
      0.2 Range[-10, 10]}], 
    Table[{x, 
      MaTeX["", "DisplayStyle" -> False, Magnification -> 0.001]}, {x,
       0.2 Range[-10, 10]}]}}]
```

However, I've noticed that each plot requires customizing the vertical ticks. I'm wondering if there's an option available to automatically assign vertical ticks while preserving the LaTeX format.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Replace with

```
myYtick[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[
    Mod[i, 0.5] == 0, {i, MaTeX[Rationalize[i]], {.03, 0.0}, 
     Black}, {i, Null, {0.01, 0.0}}], {i, Ceiling[min], 
    Floor[max], .1}];
myXtick[min_, max_] := 
  Table[If[
    Mod[i, 1] == 0, {i, MaTeX[Rationalize[i]], {.03, 0.0}, Black}, {i,
      Null, {0.01, 0.0}}], {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], .1}];

Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{myYtick, Automatic}, {myXtick, Automatic}}, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you do not want fractions, but decimals like Mathematica shows, then simply change `MaTeX[Rationalize[i]]` with `MaTeX[i]` and the output now looks like

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want the minor tick to be shorter, change `{i, MaTeX[i], {.03, 0.0}, Black}` to `{i, MaTeX[i], {.02, 0.0}, Black}`

Answer (score 0):

I think I fund one asnwer:

```
<< MaTeX`
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2, 2}, Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Map[{#, MaTeX[#, "DisplayStyle" -> False, "Magnification" -> 1.1]} &, FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 8]], 
    Map[{#, MaTeX[#, "DisplayStyle" -> False, "Magnification" -> 0.2]} &, FindDivisions[{-2, 2}, 24]]},
   {Map[{#, MaTeX[#, "DisplayStyle" -> False, "Magnification" -> 1.2]} &, FindDivisions[{-1, 1}, 5]], 
    Map[{#, MaTeX[#, "DisplayStyle" -> False, "Magnification" -> 0.001]} &, FindDivisions[{-1, 1}, 10]]}
 }
]
```

In this code, one adjust the parameters between the Max and Min of the function.